# How to get user profile from google api using python oauth2client

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I have below code from python oauth2client to process auth code that was sent from mobile app:

```
credentials = client.credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code(
                        app.config.get('GG_APP_SECRET'),
                        ['profile'],
                        authCodeFromMobileApp,
                        redirect_uri='http://example.com')
```

from that code i manage to received:

```
credentials: {
    'azp': 'some-R4nDomCh4r4c73Rs.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'aud': '4not-hersDomCh4r4c73Rs.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'sub': '114999924429522145999',
    'email': 'my.email@gmail.com',
    'email_verified': True,
    'at_hash': '50m3H4sh3D7n_ch4R4c73rg',
    'iss': 'accounts.google.com',
    'iat': 1499614999,
    'exp': 1499618999
}
```

questions:

from that result, how do i get user profiles?
my objective is to get: fname, lname, DOB and gender

Comment: have you read https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/

Comment: Yes i have read that, it is not really the same with my case and didnt tell how to use jwt token to get user profile from  backend server

Comment: you can't use a JWT token to obtain profile information. You need to make a separate API call.

Comment: Thanks @pinoyyid, Yes i can make separate api call, but how i make separate api call from above credentials that i have?